# incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to ‘int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)m) -1)) 1)]’

Tags: c, sorting

The following C code gives an error:

```
incompatible types in assignment of ‘int’ to 
‘int [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)m) -1)) 1)]’
```

On the lines where I call the recursive functions:

```
int mergeSort(int arr[], int n)
{
    if (n > 1) {
        int m = (int)(n / 2);
        int A1[m];            // array 1 --> 1 TO M
        int A2[n-m];          // array 2 --> M + 1 TO N

        int temp = m+1;
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (i == m) break;
            A1[i] = arr[i];
            A2[i] = arr[temp++];
        }

        A1 = mergeSort(A1, m); //error happens here, assigning an 
                               //integer into an integer array.

        A2 = mergeSort(A2, n - m); 

        arr = merge(A1, A2); 
    }

    return arr;
}
```

What does this error mean?

Comment: Your function returns an `int`, but you're assigning the return value into `int[]`. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Anyway, this is C, not C++, as C++ doesn't allow dynamically-sized arrays (`m` is a runtime value in your case).

Comment: If it's tagged as c++, I'd think it's non-standard C++ before standard C.

Comment: @Angew Fixed horrible grammar, fixed even worse formatting, retagged.

Comment: @H2CO3 By what right did you retag?  If he's asking about C++, giving him an answer for C would not help him.  (Actually, the only real answer for C would be to move to C++.  Doing something like this right in C requires a real expert; you either have to do the work in place, or you have to deal with dynamic allocations.)

Comment: @Angew I thought VLAs were introduced in C++ with the latest standard?

Comment: @Lundin No. [dcl.array] still requires the array bounds (if present) to be an *integral constant expression greater than zero.*

Comment: @Lundin What may be confusing is that C++11 requires binary compatibility with a C99-conforming implementation (for `extern "C"`), and C99 supports VLAs. However, VLAs are one of the bits of C99 that were not made part of C++ directly.

Answer (score 2):

There are several errors:

- C++ doesn't support variable length arrays (`A1[m]`) - use a `std::vector` instead.
- even if it did, arrays can't be reassigned, so `A1 =...` is illegal
- even if they could, you couldn't assign a single `int` to them. `mergeSort` returns an `int` (why is that?)

Comment: From the code, what I think he's trying to do is return the array.  Which, because arrays are broken, isn't possible.  With C style arrays, the return type should be `int*`, _but_ that leads to some other issues.  Your first line says it all: use `std::vector`.  Do that, declare the return type to be a vector as well, and all his problems should be solved.

Answer (score 0):

Your problems are mostly related to the fact that C style arrays
are broken, and shouldn't be used.  Just replace all of the
C style arrays with `std::vector`, and your problems should
disappear.  Except for the return value, which (from the looks
of things) should also be `std::vector<int>`.

Answer (score 0):

**Barebones program to produce the above error:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int (*p)[ 5 ]; //p is "a pointer to an array of 5 ints".

    p[0] = 10;     //Try to assign the integer 10 to array int[5]?  NO!

    //You get:
    //error: incompatible types in assignment of `int' to `int[5]'
}
```

You can't assign an int into an array of ints.  You have to dereference it first like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int (*p)[ 5 ];  //p is "a pointer to an array of 5 ints". 
    *p[0] = 10;     //assign the integer 10 to position 0 of the 
                    //array where p is pointing.

    cout << *p[0];  //prints 10.    no error thrown.
}
```