# C++ Invalid initialization error with function pointers

Tags: c++, templates, function-pointers

I'm working with pointers to template functions, the functions have array reference
arguments, for example:

```
template< size_t N >
double MyFunction( double (&x)[N] );
```

and I'll employ the previous function type like an argument in another function

```
template< size_t N >
bouble BigFunction( double (* PtrFunc)( double (&)[N] ), ... ) {
    double x[3];
    ...
    // fill x
    // call PtrFunc
    double y = (* PtrFunc)( x ); // error: ...
    ...
}
```

In main program I call `double z = BigFunction( &MyFunction, ... )` but when I tried to compile with GCC 4.7.2, I get the following error for the specific case for an array with N = 3 (the case is unimportant only explains the [3] in the error)

**error:** invalid initialization of reference of type ‘double (&)[3]’ from expression of type ‘double [(((sizetype)(((ssizetype)dim[1]) + -1))+ 1)]’

**How can I fix the problem still using an array reference?**

**Note.-** If I replace the pointer argument by a structure with a typedef or with a std::function< double( double (&)[N] ) > the problem is the same.

Here a complete example at [ideone](http://ideone.com/oWef7L)

Comment: Based on the compiler error, I think the case actually *is* important. Can you show how you call `BigFunction()`, and the declarations of all arguments you use in the call?

Comment: Related?: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14729458/1458030

Comment: I make the call of the function just like that `BigFunction( &MyFunction )` and inside of `BigFunction` I have an array `double x[3]` and I call `(* PtrFunc)( x )`, the error is presented in this line

Comment: @PedroGuarderas Just `BigFunction(&MyFunction)` should not compile, as the compiler can't possibly deduce `N` in this context. Can you post a [minimal, complete example](http://sscce.org/) reproducing the error? Something we could just paste into [ideone](http://ideone.com/), for example.

Comment: That famous built-in type `bouble`

Answer (score 0):

in your example at http://ideone.com/oWef7L
change line 24 from

```
double x[M];
```

to

```
double x[N];
```

This compiles without errors: http://ideone.com/VouWlG